# jQuery animate two divs simultaneously

Tags: jquery, animation

I wish to animate two divs, so that they simulate the sliding in/out of a sidebar.

What I have works, but not well as you can see from this

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aJA9b/)

Specific problems:

1. When divs animate, the right div changes vertical size for no apparent reason
2. The divs animate at different speeds
3. Animation is not smooth

---

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="main"></div>
    <div id="sideNavBar"></div>
</div><!-- #container -->
<input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Click Me" />
```

jQuery:

```
var state=true;

$('#mybutt').click(function() {
    if (state) {
        $('#main').animate({width:'+=28.5%'},2000);
        $('#sideNavBar').animate({width:'-=31%'},2000);
    }else{
        $('#main').animate({width:'-=30%'},2000);
        $('#sideNavBar').animate({width:'+=28.3%'},2000);
    }

    state = (state)?false:true;
});
```

css:

```
body{border:1px solid red;}
#container{height:500px;width:100%;}
#main{height:500px;width:70%;background:yellow;float:left;}
#sideNavBar{height:500px;width:30%;float:right;background:blue;}
```

Comment: Might have more luck with CSS transitions. Remove all your `.animate()` calls, use `.width()` to set the new width on each element, and have `transition: width 2.0s ease; -webkit-transition: width 2.0s ease;` in the CSS to produce the smooth animation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calculate the width and use px instead of percentage:

```
var sidebarWidth = $('#sideNavBar').width();

$('#mybutt').click(function() {
    if (state) {
        $('#main').animate({width:'+=' +sidebarWidth+'px'},2000);
        $('#sideNavBar').animate({width:'-=' + sidebarWidth + 'px'},2000);
    }else{ 
        $('#main').animate({width:'-='+sidebarWidth+'px'},2000);
        $('#sideNavBar').animate({width:'+=' + sidebarWidth+'px'},2000);
    }

    state = (state)?false:true;
});
```

see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aJA9b/1/

Comment: Just today found [the SO API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/) that allows me to [search through my previously asked questions for any without an accepted answer.](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/unaccepted-questions-on-users)  Sorry took so long to accept this answer, it was buried under years of activity. Your answer was absolutely correct. Thanks very much for your help. accept +1